# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. api.reseller.world

Tags: c#, .net, api, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I try to **get domain whois info** by using http://api.reseller.world/#api-Domain-GetInfo, got this error: **The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
string apiAddress = "https://api.reseller.world/v1.4/dms/domain/{0}";
string api = string.Format(apiAddress, domainName);
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(api);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer token");
request.Method = HttpMethod.Get.ToString();
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";

HttpWebResponse response;
try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    var resp = we.Response as HttpWebResponse;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Look at your link.  There are optional parameters.  All other parameters are required and you are missing most of the required parameters.  The 400 error indicates the server doesn't like the hedaders.

Comment: @jdweng I doing just like what we have here http://api.reseller.world/#api-Domain-GetInfo , can get what I missed to send

Comment: The new link says 400 is one of the parameters is missing.

Comment: @jdweng Please write what I missed

Answer (score 1):

See image below "Required Parameter Missing"

[image]

Comment: I'm talking about "get domain whois info", and you are talking about "get list of specific type domain"

Comment: All the 400 errors are due to the request being bad.  Maybe not missing parameters, but syntax the is bad.

Answer (score 0):

I read your code and api documention and find a different in the URL you used

> https://api.reseller.world/v1.4/dms/domain/{0}

that after formating somting look like this

> https://api.reseller.world/v1.4/dms/domain/something.something

And documention url

> https://api.reseller.world/v1.4/dms/domain/:domainName

After formating

> https://api.reseller.world/v1.4/dms/domain/:something.something

Different is ":"

But I have no api key to test this ideia

Or may be you need to set **UserAgent Property** of your's request. As far as I can remember, C# does not set this property.